# This webpage has a redirect loop, Spring application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a web application in the following environment.

- Spring 3.2.2 (recently upgraded from Spring 3.2.0).
- Spring Security 3.2.0 M1.
- Hibernate 4.2.0 CR1.
- Apache Tomcat 7.0.35.0.
- Oracle 10g.
- NetBeans 7.2.1 with jdk-7u11.

The application runs on this base URL : `http://localhost:8080/wagafashion/`. It has no problem, everything goes fine.

Since I'm using Spring security, the action of the login page is mapped with `j_spring_security_check`.

After successful login, if I enter this URL : `http://localhost:8080/wagafashion/j_spring_security_check` in the address bar (either accidentally or deliberately), then the page is redirected to the home page, the first page which is given to an authenticated user, with the following message in Google Chrome,

> This webpage has a redirect loop

As can be seen in the following [snap shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SP9U7.png).

[image]
No page can be accessed once this happens. I'm currently using the following browsers.

- Google Chrome 26.0.1410.64 m
- FireFox 20.0.1
- Internet Explorer 8

This requires cookies to be cleared to resume the application. Can this be a problem somewhere in my application. How to fix this?

---

My `spring-security.xml` file is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <http pattern="/Login.htm*" security="none"></http>    

    <http auto-config='true' use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">
    <!--<remember-me key="myAppKey"/>-->
        <session-management session-fixation-protection="newSession">
            <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
        </session-management>

        <intercept-url pattern="/admin_side/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" requires-channel="any"/>
        <form-login login-page="/" default-target-url="/admin_side/Home.htm" authentication-failure-url="/LoginFailed.htm" authentication-success-handler-ref="loginSuccessHandler"/>
        <logout logout-success-url="/Login.htm" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
       <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
               users-by-username-query="select email_id, password, enabled from user_table where lower(email_id)=lower(?)"
               authorities-by-username-query="select ut.email_id, ur.authority from user_table ut, user_roles ur where ut.user_id=ur.user_id and lower(ut.email_id)=lower(?)"/>
       </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="loginSuccessHandler" class="loginsuccesshandler.LoginSuccessHandler"/>

    <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="false">
        <protect-pointcut expression="execution(* dao.*.*(..))" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    </global-method-security>
</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your setup it gave the same result as you. To solve the problem I did this,

In security.xml change:

```
<form-login login-page="/"...
<form-login login-page="/Login.htm"...
```

Comment: Given a try. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to make a difference. Thank you.

Comment: The problem in question happens after successful login. After successful login, if an attempt is made to explicitly map the action to `j_spring_security_check`, then it causes an infinite loop. I expect it to redirect to the `Home.htm` page that doesn't happen. Does it have to do something with authentication failure?

Comment: If you explicitly call `j_spring_security_check` it'll close the user session.

Comment: Created this class and registered it as a bean in the `spring-security.xml` file but it again causes the same infinite loop.

Comment: Change `<form-login login-page="/"...` for `<form-login login-page="/Login.htm"...`

Comment: The thing remains as it was.

Comment: `<form-login login-page="/"...` is in the question.